# Best way to register js for modularity in User Control

Tags: jquery, .net, user-controls, relative-path, resolveurl

i have a control that is organized like this

[image]

and i want to have the javascript registered on the calling master pages, etc, so that anywhere this control folder is dropped and then registered, it will know how to find the URL to the js.

Here is what i have so far (in the user control )

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jqModal"))
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jqModal", ResolveClientUrl("~js/jqModal.js"));
    if (!Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jQuery"))
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", ResolveClientUrl("~/js/jQuery.js"));
    if (!Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("tellAFriend"))
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("tellAFriend", ResolveClientUrl("js/tellAFriend.js"));
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper class with static method:

```
public static class PageHelper {
    public static void RegisterClientScriptIfNeeded( Page page, string key, string url ) {
        if( false == page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered( key )) {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude( key , ResolveClientUrl( url ));
        }
    }
}
```

or you can have a similar instance method in some base class for page/webcontrol/usercontrol, which will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the image you posted.

You could also use Context.Items to ensure that the item is only added once per request and render the javascript through the control itself, although I think the registerclient script is great too.

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
        string[] items = new string[] { "jqModal", "jQuery", "tellAFriend" };
        //Check if the Script has already been rendered during this request.
        foreach(string jsFile in items)
        {          
            if (!Context.Items.Contain(sjsFile))
            {
                //Specify that the Script has been rendered during this request.
                Context.Items.Add(jsFile,true);
                //Write the script to the page via the control
                writer.Write(string.Format(SCRIPTTAG, ResolveUrl(jsFile)));
            }
        }
     }
```